# Node with zod validator and class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class

im trying to use this function convertError to convert error from zod, but i always get that return:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatError' of undefined

```
import { IMiddlewaresRules } from "../IMiddlewaresRules";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { figureBodySchema } from "../zodschemas/schemasZod";
import { ZodError } from "zod";

class FormatError {
  convertError(
    err: ZodError
  ): Array<{ message: string; key: (string | number)[]; code: number }> {
    return err.issues.map((err) => {
      const error = {
        message: err.message,
        key: err.path,
        code: 400,
      };
      return error;
    });
  }
}

export class VerifyRequestsBody implements IMiddlewaresRules {
  constructor(private formatError: FormatError) {}

  verifyBodyFigure(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
  ): Response | any {
    const { data } = req.body;

    try {
      figureBodySchema.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof ZodError) {
        return res.status(400).json(this.formatError.convertError(err));
      }
    }
    next();
  }

}
```

i don't understand why this happen, i already define the function before

full code here:
https://github.com/DanielTrybe/backend-figures/tree/1.2.0-middleware

Comment: How do you call `verifyBodyFigure`? How do you instantiate `VerifyRequestsBody`?

Comment: its a node, my code is here https://github.com/DanielTrybe/backend-figures/tree/1.2.0-middleware and i call with a post

Comment: @HeikoTheißen it's typescript actually, and by annotating the constructor parameter with  `private` the property will be created implicitly

Comment: [Here's your problem](https://github.com/DanielTrybe/backend-figures/blob/a1770f6c786a73a7084daf3bf43d79fbcae3e0e8/src/routes/post/routes.ts#L6-L11). You did not bind the methods to the instance.

Comment: i dont understand, all works without that convertError, if i set the map in catch like that:      if (err instanceof ZodError) {
        return res.status(400).json(
          err.issues.map((err) => {
            const error = {
              message: err.message,
              key: err.path,
              code: 400,
            };
            return error;
          })
        );
      } , it works

Comment: The problem is that you're attempting to reference `this.formatError` in an unbound method. The problem is not with `convertError` itself, or even to do with zod.

Comment: i'm confused, but how i bound that function to work like a help function for this class?

Comment: Did you read the duplicate targets?

Comment: duplicate targets? what do you mean

Comment: ohh i understand now what im doing wrong, i update the coede and now works, thanks